# made it impossible not to have an outburst

Tags: meaning, infinitives, ellipsis

a. I had an outburst of anger when I was talking to John. He was extremely rude. He really made it impossible for me not to have an outburst.

b. I had an outburst of anger when I was talking to John. He was extremely rude. He really made it impossible not to have an outburst.

Can one use (b) instead of (a)?

Is there any difference in their meanings?

Answer (score 1):

They have identical meanings but out of the 2 I would say B is more correct.

However, mentioning the word 'outburst' twice like that is a little redundant (not necessary).

I would phrase it like:

> John was extremely rude and talking to him made me very angry. He really
> made it impossible not to have an outburst.

Answer (score 1):

No, the meaning is not necessarily the same. Moreover, the second sentence is awkwardly phrased.

The first sentence states that you burst into anger in response to John's rudeness.

The second sentence implies it, But it is not idiomatic. Nor, for that matter, is the first.

We don't say that people make it impossible (for others) not to have an outburst.

Apart from anything, both examples indicate that you use hyperbole and lack self control. But that's an aside.

If you mean that John tried your patience to the limits, or gave such offence that you had an angry outburst, say so.

Answer (score 1):

While the meaning of a and b could be different, their most probable meanings are much the same. While b leaves itr open who had the outburst, the obvious implication is that it was the speaker.

However "had an outburst of anger" in in my view an akwrd phrase. It doesn't clearly indicate what the person actually did. Yelled? pounded the table? Punched John? Using "outburst" twice in close succession only makes the issue worse, again in my view.

I would rework this statement, perhaps to something like:

> - I spoke angrily to John just now. He was extremely rude. He really made it impossible for me to keep my temper.
> - I spoke angrily to John when we discussed X. He was extremely rude. He really made it impossible for me to keep my temper.

Th speaker here says more clearly what happened, and does not use an awkwardly repeated construction,